# How to make customised mod-rewrite in .htaccess file?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This is my .htaccess file. On invalid request it will redirect user to home page.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

How to tweak this code to redirect it when user enter for example "admin" phrase on the end of my website url. For example:

```
www.mywebsite.com/admin
```

so it will go to:

```
www.mywebsite.com/admin.php
```

I have tried this but it did not work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /admin
RewriteRule /admin http://www.mywebsite.com/admin.php
```

How to make customised Rewrite in .htaccess file ?

Comment: I assume that you meant to have it "tweaked" instead of "tweeted"

Comment: corrected my typo thx ! :)

Answer (score 0):

I just worked it out myself. Directly under "RewriteEngine On" line, I added the 
following code:

```
RewriteRule ^admin/?$ admin.php [L]
```

Works for me. Hope you will also find it useful.